# AngularJS two instances of the same directive update each other

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Like the title says i have two instances of the same directive, on startup both has the same data. how do i make them update each other when each one of them changes?

```
myApp.directive('locationSelector',function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'App/Common/templates/locationSelectorTemplate.html',
        scope: {
            someValue: '@val'
        },
        controller: function ($scope, locationsService) {
          // get the available locations from service
          $scope.locations = locationsService.getLocations();
          // select the first option as the default value for the ng-options
          $scope.location = $scope.locations[0];

          // do something when the other directive value changes
          // 
          //

        },
        link: function (scope,element,attrs) {

        }
    };
});
```

So for example lets say they both start with values: `{'a','b','c'}`
now suppose user selected `'b'` on the first directive the second directive should change to `'c'`. and later on the user selected `'a'` on the second directive and now the first one should change to `'a'` (the logic for the change is not important for this example).

Comment: you may need to look into the use of require when defining a directive to get the controller from another directive.  Alternatively you could use an angular.service or angular.value to define some object that is then shared by the directives, another option is to use events to communicate between the directives using $emit $broadcast and $on

Comment: I prefer not to use a global object or service to communicate.

Comment: In that case your basically down to using require so you can access the controller in the docs check out the section "Creating directives that communicate" http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive I think that will work for you, otherwise events are the other option but I think the require is ultimately the best way to go this way the directives just need to be "aware" of each other.  Alternatively you could use events, but you might get into a situation where you end up creating a ton of events.

Comment: Ok but what exactly i need to require? it makes sense if i had two different directives lets say a and b and b require a and vice-versa. but in my case they are just instances of the same directive. Can you provide example?

Comment: See the answer below, it seems to cover the explanation.  Basically have a second directive that acts as the controller for all the "sibling" directives that you intended on creating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directive controller is the way to go, that's the exact use case of it, i.e. an API between directives. What you need to do is extract your directive controller functionality into its own *container* directive, and have your `locationSelector` directive `require` this container directive to gain access to its controller.

This is the exact way directives like form and its associated input/ngModel directives communicate. Each input directive registers with a parent form directive controller for stuff like validation etc.

There are already numerous excellent examples of how to implement this, here are a couple of examples with links to the source:

angular-ui bootstrap [Tabs](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/tabs/tabs.js): https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/tabs/tabs.js

```
<tabset vertical="true" type="navType">
  <tab heading="Vertical 1">Vertical content 1</tab>
  <tab heading="Vertical 2">Vertical content 2</tab>
</tabset>
```

In the above example the `tabset` directive is the *container* directive with controller.

angular-ui bootstrap [Accordian](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/accordion/accordion.js): https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/accordion/accordion.js

Angular form directive: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/form.js
Angular input and ngModel directives: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/input.js

Comment: Thanks these are great examples. one thing i haven't figured out is where the change logic should occur? in the parent controller, in the group directive (tabset or in my case flightSelectorsGroup) or in the child directive itself (tab or in my case loctionSelector)?

Comment: @baba-dev I would say the change logic will all sit at the pareent controller. So if you child directive detect a change, it will call the relevant change functions in the parent controller.